# Can I use "fixed" as antonym of "broken"?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, past-participles

I am wondering to know when something is broken, after repairing, can I say `it is fixed` or should I say `it has been fixed`. Can I used `fixed` as an adjective and antonym of `broken`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Fixed' used as an antonym of 'broken' or 'damaged' is a mainly US informal word, and 'repaired' would be better in formal writing.

Answer (score 0):

"It is fixed" and "it has been fixed" are both perfectly correct expressions. The difference is one of emphasis. In both cases the object is fixed. If you say "it is fixed" your focus is on current condition of the object. But if you say "it has been fixed" your focus is also on the time in the past when it was fixed.

Fixed and broken are certainly opposites, but I'm not sure if they are strict antonyms. The obvious antonym for *broken* is *unbroken*. More importantly, both words are past participles and can be used grammatically in the same way. For example, both of these sentences are correct:

1. I took the broken vase to the repair shop.
2. I collected the fixed vase from the repair shop.